# Troubleshooting Windows Event Viewer USB error 0x26 status 0xc000038e

Tags: usb, drivers, event-viewer, windbg

I need some guidance in how to troubleshoot a low level issue I am facing with some USB devices.

**Background**: I have a `.NET Windows Service` that, scans `connected USB devices via WMI queries` + reads [low level USB data](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/usbcon/usb-device-layout) using `external C code`.

Although happening seldomly, once in a while a USB device (keyboard, mouse or smart card reader) stops functioning.
Looking at Windows's `Device Manager`, the device shows with a yellow triangle with an exclamation mark.
Looking at `Event Viewer`'s `Microsoft-Windows-Kernel PnP`, I see the following error (for [mouse](https://devicehunt.com/view/type/usb/vendor/03F0/device/094A), in this case)

[image]

**XML View:**

```
- <Event xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/event">
- <System>
  <Provider Name="Microsoft-Windows-Kernel-PnP" Guid="{9c205a39-1250-487d-abd7-e831c6290539}" /> 
  <EventID>411</EventID> 
  <Version>0</Version> 
  <Level>2</Level> 
  <Task>0</Task> 
  <Opcode>0</Opcode> 
  <Keywords>0x4000000000000000</Keywords> 
  <TimeCreated SystemTime="2022-12-22T08:15:21.1540378Z" /> 
  <EventRecordID>300</EventRecordID> 
  <Correlation /> 
  <Execution ProcessID="4" ThreadID="3780" /> 
  <Channel>Microsoft-Windows-Kernel-PnP/Configuration</Channel> 
  <Computer>MyComputerName</Computer> 
  <Security UserID="S-1-5-18" /> 
  </System>
- <EventData>
  <Data Name="DeviceInstanceId">USB\VID_03F0&PID_094A\6&1ab5e341&0&2</Data> 
  <Data Name="DriverName">input.inf</Data> 
  <Data Name="ClassGuid">{745a17a0-74d3-11d0-b6fe-00a0c90f57da}</Data> 
  <Data Name="ServiceName">HidUsb</Data> 
  <Data Name="LowerFilters" /> 
  <Data Name="UpperFilters" /> 
  <Data Name="Problem">0x26</Data> 
  <Data Name="Status">0xc000038e</Data> 
  </EventData>
  </Event>
```

**How does one proceed from here?**

There is no clear indication that the error is caused by the interactions with my .NET Service.
In any case, I guess I need to figure out how are such messages written to Windows' [ETW](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/etw/event-tracing-portal). From there, try to locate where in the C code there is a hook or piece of code that feeds the given ETW listener.

1. Is this the right track? Are there shorter alternatives? Am I missing anything else?
2. Could not find conclusive info on what does the `0x26` error/`0xc000038e` status codes mean. Is  there a specific resource for that?
3. Is there a way I can dump data from such error instances into a tool like [Windows Debugger](http://www.windbg.org/) so it loads the the state of all the parts involved - and perhaps help ?
4. Identify the installed driver for this specific device - and search for logs it eventually writes?

Comment: The problem posed is "I need guidance in what is the way to troubleshoot this". How can this be precised/focused any more ? I went on to raise myself possibilities on that. But I want guidance from someone knowledgeable in usb/drivers/windows internals/etc.